# Are there non normal subgroups $H, T$ of group $G$ such that $HT$ is subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am asking whether the converse of the following theorem is true:

( $H$ is normal) or ( $T$ is normal) $\implies$ $HT$ is subgroup of $G$.

My motivation is that I am interested in normal subgroups. I recently had a funny coincidence while trying to solve a question that asked me to give an example of subgroups $H$ and $T$ such that $HT$ is not a subgroup. I had to try non-normal subgroups in non-abelian groups, but the first non-abelian group I tried, the Quaternions $Q8$ , consists only of normal subgroups.
But I am done with the question of finding example of subgroups $H$ and $T$ such that $HT$ is not a subgroup , when I tried $D_{4}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff either $H$ or $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157013/is-it-true-that-hk-is-a-subgroup-of-g-iff-either-h-or-k-is-a-normal-subg) See also [When is $HK$ a subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658564).

Comment: They are both good as answer for my question